# Strange behavior trying to add views programmatically to a ContraintLayout in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am coming to Android from an iOS developer background and am having some difficulty getting ConstraintLayout to work correctly when adding views programatically.

I have a very simple activity with a ConstraintLayout and a single button that I placed inside of the Android Studio design window.  When the button is pressed I am adding a textView and another button.  I am trying to constrain these such that they are the same distance from the top of the ConstraintLayout, and the leading edge of the textView is constrained to the left side of the ConstraintLayout, and the button is constrained to the right side of the ConstraintLayout.

My XML follows:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/parentViewConstraintLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <Button
       android:id="@+id/addWidgetButton"
       style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
       android:text="Add New Widget"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the Kotlin in question

```
addWidgetButton.setOnClickListener() {

    val textView = TextView(this)
    textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
    textView.setTextSize(20f)
    textView.setText("Text message for testing")

    val newButton = Button(this)
    newButton.setText("Push me")

    parentViewConstraintLayout.addView(textView)
    parentViewConstraintLayout.addView(newButton)

    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(parentViewConstraintLayout)

    constraintSet.connect(textView.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, parentViewConstraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 10)
    constraintSet.connect(textView.id, ConstraintSet.START, parentViewConstraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.START, 10)

    constraintSet.connect(newButton.id, ConstraintSet.END, parentViewConstraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.END, 30)
    constraintSet.connect(newButton.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, parentViewConstraintLayout.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, 50)

    constraintSet.applyTo(parentViewConstraintLayout)
}
```

When the button is pressed, instead of the expected behavior I get this:
[image]

If I comment out some code so that I only add one view (either the button or the textView) it works correctly.  There is some strange interaction between them that I don't understand.

Comment: I suggest you use something like a RecyclerView. It is better equipped to handle dynamic views of the same type

Comment: Various comments before we can move on. 1. What version of CL are you using? 2. Remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom=“true”` and `android:layout_centerHorizontal=“true”` they belong on RelativeLayout, and will be ignored here.

Comment: implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'  The XML code in question for Button was generated by the designer in Android Studio for the Add New Widget button at the bottom of the screen.  It is actually working as advertised.  Not sure why it is there if it is incorrect or will be ignored.

Comment: Ok, if possible I suggest you use `1.1.0` (since you use `wrap_content`in your widgets, there are plenty of bug fixes around that). Also, do assign Ids (as indicated in the answer below by @Cheticamp). The incorrect XML is because the design builder makes _questionable_ decisions ;)

Comment: I will try both changes and report back.

Comment: I’m interested if `textView.id` has an actual id _magically_ generated or not. I’ll look into your constraints.

Comment: Lol on design builder...live by the crutch die by the crutch.  This is so far turning out to be a vertical learning curve coming from Xcode and iOS.

Comment: I added an answer without a real answer. I’ll try something and update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` constraints work with resource ids. I see where you create the `TextView` and `Button`, but I don't see where you set the ids for these views. Maybe some Kotlin magic?

For API 17+, you can use [`View.generateViewId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()) to generate the id and [`View.setId()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)) to set it. You can then refer to the ids in the `ConstraintSet`. Right now they are both [`View.NO_ID`.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#NO_ID).

I will also add that if you want to refer to the parent as a constraint it is [`ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#PARENT_ID).

Comment: While I am giving credit for the answer here...kudos also to  Martin Marconcini for his suggestions and for pointing out I was not using the latest version of constraintLayouts.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to constrain these such that they are the same distance from the top of the ConstraintLayout, and the leading edge of the textView is constrained to the left side of the ConstraintLayout, and the button is constrained to the right side of the ConstraintLayout.

Ok, so if I don’t get that wrong… what you want is a TextView and a Button side by side, correct?

`| [TextView]                    [Button]|`

or

`|         [TextView][Button]            |`

or

`| [TextView        ][Button            ]|`

or

?

Depending what you want, the constraints have to be different.

Additionally, you say:

> they are the same distance from the top of the ConstraintLayout

This means that they will effectively be on top of the previous one if you keep pressing the button, is this intended?

Or did you mean “I want them below the previous, respecting the “top margin” so the vertical space between each element is the same?”

In any case, you should (since you’re using CL 1.0.2) correctly specify all the attributes of these Views.

Think of AutoLayout, unless a View has an intrinsic size, you need to pin the start/end/top/bottom before the algorithm can determine where the view must go.

Anyway back to your sample…

I added

`textView.id = View.generateViewId()`

and

`newButton.id = View.generateViewId()`

and ran your code and it works… but each new “pair” of button/text is added on top.

If you need to do `|[Tv              ][btn]|` you can simply add these two:

`textView.layoutParams = Constraints.LayoutParams(ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT, ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT)`

and

`constraintSet.connect(textView.id, ConstraintSet.END, newButton.id, ConstraintSet.START, 10)`

that should give you that.

Comment: Was trying to get the top example you give.  Was working very piecemeal.  Next would be to stretch textView from left side all the way to the button [text-----------------------------view ][button] then to capture the ids so that the next push drops the same thing but anchored to ones I just built.

Comment: so you want `|[TV………….][btn]|` ?

Comment: Yes, but for now I was simply trying to keep it as simple as possible just to get the constraints working.

Comment: Yeah, that should do. You will need to keep track of the last id to pin newTV.top to prevTV.bottom and such. In fact, I’d constraint each new one, to the previous, that way they are all constrained together.

Comment: Changed to version 1.1.0 now getting the following exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: All children of ConstraintLayout must have ids to use ConstraintSet,  I also have the following in there now:             textView.setId(View.generateViewId()) & newButton.setId(View.generateViewId()) so I am not sure what the problem is now.

Comment: Working well now.  I accidentally was setting the ids after I called constraintSet.clone().  Fixed that and now it seems to be working as advertised.  Just needed to give the ids.  Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Good to hear, check updated answer if you need to do the tv….btn layout. ;) Good luck!

Comment: The last part of your solution is not working as expected.  Trying to set it up so that the button is fixed width and the textView or editView fills the rest of the screen.  In other words the editView will vary in size based on the screen size of the device.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to add the following: constraintSet.constrainWidth(editText.id, ConstraintSet.MATCH_CONSTRAINT) and constraintSet.constrainHeight(editText.id, 200)